# Replacing user portion of email address in java

Tags: java, string, email, replace

You have

```
user.nick@domain.com
```

and result should be:

```
******@domain.com
```

Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
public static String removeUserFromEmail(String email) {
    StringBuffer sbEmail = new StringBuffer(email);
    int start = sbEmail.indexOf("@");
    sbEmail.delete(0, start);
    return "******" + sbEmail.toString();
}
```

Is there something simpler or more elegant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with that solution, although I have two suggestions:

1) Use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer unless you need to synchronize access between multiple threads.  There is a performance penalty associated with StringBuffer that for this application is likely unnecessary.

2) One of the benefits of StringBuilder/Buffer is avoiding excessive string concatenations.

Your return line converts the Buffer to a string, and then concatenates.  I would probably do this instead:

```
int start = email.indexOf("@");

if (start < 0) {
    return "";  // pick your poison for the error condition
}

StringBuilder sbEmail = new StringBuilder(email);
sbEmail.replace(0, start, "******");
return sbEmail.toString();
```

FYI - my solution is really just some thoughts on your current use of StringBuffer (which are hopefully helpful).  I would recommend Konstantin's solution for this simple string exercise.  Simple, readable, and it gives you the opportunity to handle the error condition.

Comment: +1 cause I thought about the String concatenation penalty too. But, StringBuilder/StringBuffer in this situation seems like micro-optimization to me.

Comment: @orange I agree. Although I tend to use it without even thinking.  You never know when your concatenations might sneak their way into a loop.

Answer (score 5):

i would be inclined to run indexOf on email string before putting it in the stringbuffer...

```
int start = email.indexOf( '@' );

if( start == -1 )
{
   // handle invalid e-mail
}
else
{
   return "*****" + email.substring( start );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"some.user@domain.com".replaceAll("^[^@]+", "******");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String removeUserFromEmail(String email) {
    String[] pieces = email.split("@");
    return (pieces.length > 1 ? "******" + pieces[1] : email);
}
```

Comment: will fail hard if @ is not in the string

Comment: @landon9720: fair enough, think the ternary operator addresses this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks OK. Better check if `indexOf` returns `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex, but your solution seems fine to me. Probably faster than the regex too.